# Slicing on entire panda dataframe instead of series results in change of data type and values assignment of first field to NaN, what is happening?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

Was trying to do some cleaning on a dataset ,where instead providing a condition on a panda series
`head_only[head_only.BasePay > 70000]`
I applied the condition on the data frame
`head_only[head_only > 70000]`
attached images of my observation, could anyone help me understand what is it that's happening ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: so if use `head_only[head_only > 70000]` then it not return `TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'` or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution raise error if numeric with strings columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2.0,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df[df > 5])
```

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

If compare only numeric columns it get values higher like `4` and all another numbers convert to misisng values:

```
df1 = df.select_dtypes(np.number)
print (df1[df1 > 4])
     B    C    D    E
0  NaN  7.0  NaN  5.0
1  5.0  8.0  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  9.0  5.0  6.0
3  5.0  NaN  7.0  9.0
4  5.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Here are replaced at least one value in each column, so integers columns are converted to floats (because `NaN` is `float`):

```
print (df1[df1 > 4].dtypes)
B    float64
C    float64
D    float64
E    float64
dtype: object
```

If need compare all numeric columns if at least one of them match condition use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for test if at least one value is `True`:

```
#returned boolean DataFrame
print ((df1 > 7))
       B      C      D      E
0  False  False  False  False
1  False   True  False  False
2  False   True  False  False
3  False  False  False   True
4  False  False  False  False
5  False  False  False  False

print ((df1 > 7).any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5    False
dtype: bool


print (df1[(df1 > 7).any(axis=1)])
   B    C  D  E
1  5  8.0  3  3
2  4  9.0  5  6
3  5  4.0  7  9
```

Or if need filter original all columns is possible filter only numeric columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
print (df[(df.select_dtypes(np.number) > 7).any(axis=1)])
   A  B    C  D  E  F
1  b  5  8.0  3  3  a
2  c  4  9.0  5  6  a
3  d  5  4.0  7  9  b
```